# How to perform alphabetically ordered DFS?

Tags: graphs, search-algorithms

I've been working on this graph and just completely botching it. I mean to say that my solution may be the worst possible other than if a monkey had thrown darts at the graph to decide the next path.  Anyhow, I'm lost and really trying to get a grasp of where my conclusion and the proper conclusion diverged dramatically.

I wanted to perform a DFS, show discovery/finish times, the DF forest, and edge classifications. I assumed that: 1) The vertices are listed in alphabetical order in each adjacency list. 2) The vertices are taken in the alphabetical order in the main loop of the DFS algorithm.

[image]

Should I be treating this as a directed acyclic graph?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking here.  You certainly have drawn directed graphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$L$ has an edge to $K$, other than that, the DFS forest you've drawn is correct.  And since $K$ would not be expanded before $L$, there should be an edge $LK$ in the BFS forest.

Comment: New users can't upvote so maybe someone else can help you out.  But yes I understand your solution and where I was going wrong.  Thanks.